# How to exclude name of directory from results when using grep recursively

Tags: bash, grep

I am trying to extract a pattern using `grep -r`. It works, except the name of the directory also gets printed out. I just need it to print out the patterns it finds instead of including the path to the pattern.

Code:

`grep -r <pattern> */<file_name_pattern>`

Results:

```
<path_to_pattern>:<pattern_result>
<path_to_pattern>:<pattern_result>
<path_to_pattern>:<pattern_result>
... etc
```

I just want:

```
<pattern_result>
<pattern_result>
<pattern_result>
...etc
```

Comment: `man grep | grep filename` :  -H, --with-filename ; -h, --no-filename

Comment: I must have looked at the --help a hundred times and I didn't spot -h. Embarrassing..

Comment: An alternative solution (that I do not recommend) could be: `grep -r PATTERN | cut -d':' -f2`